# creating word document in Android using Apache Poi

Tags: android

I have created excel file in java using Apache Poi 3.8 lib file and it worked well when integrated in Android also. but when i create a word file in java using Apache Poi 3.10 lib file it's working in java but showing errors when integrated in Android. It shows java.lang.verifyerror

Any suggestion how to solve this.

Comment: Are you trying to make a .doc file or a .docx file?

Comment: I wanted to make a .docx file.

Comment: Is it matters for making a .doc or .docx file.

Comment: .doc won't give any problem... .docx might give problem

Comment: but .doc is also giving prob and i wanted both